# True length of a String, as seen by Oracle

Tags: java, string, oracle

So I am trying to save data to an Oracle database.  I have a string:

```
Väste
```

(the name of a state somewhere).

When I do a .length() on it, I get 5, but when I save it to the database I get:

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column "dude"."POST_ADR"."STATE_CD" (actual: 6, maximum: 5)
```

So how do I get the "oracle" length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're using a composed character, you should get the underlying byte array and then get that length:

```
"Väste".getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length
```

will print out 6.

Comment: You need to specify encoding when using getBytes() otherwise getBytes() would depend on default system encoding.

Answer (score 10):

You can, as others have shown, convert the Java string to a byte array using the Oracle database's character set and then get the length in bytes from that.  That relies, however, on knowing what your database's character set is-- different databases will have different character sets which will result in different byte lengths for the same string in different character sets.

Assuming that your database is using a variable-width character set like UTF-8 (`NLS_CHARACTERSET` of AL32UTF8), you can also declare columns in Oracle based on the character length rather than the byte length.  That can simplify your code since you can just check the character length of your string.  It also simplifies the communication for users.  It's generally hard for users to understand why a field can sometimes store 5 characters while other times it rejects a 2 character string depending on the characters that are part of the string (1 character in the UTF-8 character set can require up to 3 bytes of storage).

By default, when you declare a column

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  col_name VARCHAR2(5)
);
```

that tells Oracle to allow up to 5 bytes of data.  If you want to allow 5 characters of data regardless of the number of bytes, however, you can use character length semantics

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  col_name VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)
);
```

Assuming you want to do this for all your tables while running your DDL, you can also set `nls_length_semantics` at the session level before running your DDL

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_length_semantics = CHAR;

CREATE TABLE foo (
  col_name VARCHAR2(5)
);
```

creates a table with a column that allows up to 5 characters of data.

Comment: Hi, How can i get from code actual encondig of column/ table ?I am not суре if my code run on UTF-8 оr UTF-16 base

Comment: @TNN - `v$nls_parameters` will tell you the database and national character set.  `char`, `varchar2`, and `clob` columns use the database character set.  `nchar`, `nvarchar2` and `nclob` columns use the national character set.  There is no way to choose a different character set for a particular table or column.

Answer (score 9):

Oracle is giving you the length in bytes and `"ä"` is 2 bytes in UTF-8 (c3 a4).

More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repunicode.htm).

You may get the lenght in bytes using `str.getBytes("UTF-8").length`

Comment: "So how do I get the 'oracle' length?"

Comment: Obviously.  So how do I get the "Oracle" length?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to get oracle byte length of a string using a query,

```
SELECT
   LENGTHB ('Test') "Length in bytes"
FROM
   DUAL;
```

will give result as 4.

reference: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_lengthb_lengthc_length2_length4.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getByteSize(String content) {
    int size = 0;
    if (null != content) {
        try {
            size = content.getBytes("utf-8").length;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

System.out.println(getByteSize("Väste")); // 6
System.out.println(getByteSize("Väää")); // 7